# string to json Unexpected token 's',

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, graphql

i´m trying to send to mutation `graphQL` any data from vue js to my mutation created with laravel:

```
parametrosCorreo: '{ "para":"' + destinatariosListaFmt.para.replace(/ /g, "")
                    + '", "cc":"' + destinatariosListaFmt.cc.replace(/ /g, "")
                    + '", "cco":"' + destinatariosListaFmt.cco.replace(/ /g, "")
                    + '", "aplicacion": "SIFCO"'
                    + ', "replyTo": {"email": "liquidaciones.gas@cnmc.es", "name": "Grupo Gas (Liquid)"}'  + ', "anexarComoFichero": ' + this.anexarComoFichero 
                    + ', "incrustarEnCuerpo": ' + this.incrustarEnCuerpo
                    + ', "texto": "'+ encodeURIComponent(this.mensaje)
                    + ', "adjunto": '+ JSON.stringify(this.ficheroError)
                    + ', "usuario": ' + JSON.stringify(this.usuario) 
                    +' }'
```

in my mutation, i have a function to receibe my data, and i have, `json_decode` to generate object and access to properties.

```
public function enviarMailDeTareaConParametros($root, array $args, $context)
    {
        $parametros = json_decode($args['parametrosCorreo'], true);
```

But returning me, this error:

```
Error: Network error: Unexpected token 's', "string(422"... is not valid JSON
```

In my network tab, i can show, my json:

```
string(422) "{ "para":",", "cc":"", "cco":"", "aplicacion": "", "replyTo": {"email": "", "name": ""}, "anexarComoFichero": true, "incrustarEnCuerpo": true, "texto": "Buenos%20d%C3%ADas.%20%0A%0AEl%20fichero%20ha%20entrado%20correctamente.%20%0A%0AUn%20saludo%2C, "adjunto": {"ruta":null,"numTrazas":0}, "usuario": }"
```

What i´m doing wrong? thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

**update:**

```
array(3) {
  ["tarea_id"]=>
  int(17560)
  ["usuario_id"]=>
  string(2) "80"
  ["parametrosCorreo"]=>
  string(421) "{ "para":"data,data", "cc":"", "cco":"data", "aplicacion": "data", "replyTo": {"email": "data", "name": "data"}, "anexarComoFichero": true, "incrustarEnCuerpo": true, "texto": "data", "adjunto": {"ruta":null,"numTrazas":0}, "usuario": data}"
}
```

updated 2:

```
    parametrosCorreo: '{ "para":"' + destinatariosListaFmt.para.replace(/ /g, "")
   + '", "cc":"' + destinatariosListaFmt.cc.replace(/ /g, "")
   + '", "cco":"' + destinatariosListaFmt.cco.replace(/ /g, "")
   + '", "aplicacion": "SIFCO"'
   + ', "replyTo": {"email": "liquidaciones.gas@cnmc.es", "name": "Grupo Gas (Liquid)"}' 
   + ', "anexarComoFichero": ' + this.anexarComoFichero 
   + ', "incrustarEnCuerpo": ' + this.incrustarEnCuerpo
   + ', "texto": "'+ encodeURIComponent(this.mensaje)
   + '", "adjunto": '+ JSON.stringify(this.ficheroError)
   + ', "usuario": ' + JSON.stringify(this.usuario) 
   +' }'
```

Comment: Are you using `dd()` or `dump()` or `var_dump()` somewhere we don't see? Cleared the caches?

Comment: @brombeer i updated my question with var_dump() i cleared cache

Comment: the `texto` part seems wrong (not closing the `"`), and the `usuario` as well which has no value.

Comment: @gabrielepetrioli i change my question with ```update 2``` that you can see better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know how to use the `JSON.stringify` why not use it for the whole thing instead of concatenating strings ?

```js
parametrosCorreo: JSON.stringify({
  para: destinatariosListaFmt.para.replace(/ /g, ""),
  cc: destinatariosListaFmt.cc.replace(/ /g, ""),
  cco: destinatariosListaFmt.cco.replace(/ /g, ""),
  aplicacion: "SIFCO",
  replyTo: {
    email: "liquidaciones.gas@cnmc.es",
    name: "Grupo Gas (Liquid)"
  },
  anexarComoFichero: this.anexarComoFichero,
  incrustarEnCuerpo: this.incrustarEnCuerpo,
  texto: encodeURIComponent(this.mensaje),
  adjunto: this.ficheroError,
  usuario: this.usuario
})
```

Comment: @GrabrielePetrioli thanks for your help, but with your response, returned same error